# Provide jQuery Style Encapsulatable Functions in C++

Tags: c++, oop, function

In e.g. jQuery you can encapsulate functions to execute many actions on an object in one line.

```
$('div').parent().find('a').is('.class').css('color', 'red');
```

I don't know *how* how that work internally. How can I write a class in C++ with a similar behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called method chaining and you can achieve the same effect in C++, depending on your return type.

```
struct A
{
   A& foo()
   {
     return *this;
   }
   A& goo()
   {
     return *this;
   }
};

A a;
a.foo().goo().foo();
```

This is just a simple example.